# Is the letter delta generally only used to express change in variable or quantity?

Tags: notation

I was speaking with a friend of mine earlier and he said "Oh look, delta, the sign of uncertainty" (he doesn't study physics often so had only seen in in Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle equations). I said "Actually, delta is used to express change in variable or quantity, and is only used for uncertainty in Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle and other such equations".

When I said "other such equations" I meant the ones that are identical to the most famous Uncertainty Principle equation, which just a change in variable, for example: you can't know both the direction of a rotating object and how fast it's spinning, as well as there being uncertainty in the relationship between the number of photons in a light beam and the phase wave associated with the beam (both are expressed with a similar equation to Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle and use the delta symbol to represent uncertainty.

Was I wrong? Are there other reasonably well-known equations that use the delta symbol to express a variable that isn't change in variable/quantity or uncertainty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is all convention, but I'd say $\Delta$ is more often an operator than a variable. It has the 'change of' meaning you comment, but is also used for the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).

The lowercase version, $\delta$, is more often used as a variable, most notably in all those [$\delta-\epsilon$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_definition_.28epsilon-delta.29_of_continuous_functions) definitions and theorems of calculus. It also has universal meaning as [Dirac's delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) or its discrete sister, [Kronecker's delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). And in [variational calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) it is used to represent the [variation of a functional.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation)

And there are probably a bunch of other uses I am missing.